# meta_query property doesnt work as expected in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

meta_query doesnt work with custom meta.My custom meta value is '_user_id'.Doesn't the custom meta and WC_Product_Query work together? I am waiting for your suggestions

Function.php

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

    global $woocommerce, $post;

      woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
          array( 
              'id'          => '_user_id', 
              'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
              'placeholder' => 'http://',
              'desc_tip'    => 'true',
              'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
          )
      );

  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
  function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
      $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_user_id'];
      if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
          update_post_meta( $post_id, '_user_id', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

  }
```

My WooCommerce query

```
$args = array(

    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array( 
        'key' => '_user_id',
        'value' => '11',
        'compare' => '='
    )),

);
```

Comment: Did you try setting type as numeric?